# Prove that the Collatz function is not surjective no matter what initial condition we choose.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

[image: Question statement]

Where the initial condition is $f(0)=k$ , where $k \in \mathbb{N} $

So I just started reading some discrete mathematics and this problem came up in Oscar Levin's book " An open introduction to discrete mathematics". I am pretty clueless as to how to proceed with such a question. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to think of two cases: (1) it hits $1$ (2) it does not.

Comment: how would you reach $3k+3$?

Comment: @ArcticChar , if it hits 1, it is pretty straightforward as it will keep on cycling between 1,4, 2. But how do I proceed with the "if it does not hit 1" case ?

Comment: Then $1$ is not in the image of $f$?

Comment: Ah okay got it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f^m$ denote the $m$-fold composition of $f$ with itself and
$$\begin{align}
g_n: \Bbb N_0 &\to \Bbb N\\
 m &\mapsto f^m(n)
\end{align}$$

If $n\in \{1,2,4\}$ then $g_n$ is not onto due to the cycle$$1\mapsto4\mapsto2\mapsto1\mapsto\cdots$$
in the forward-orbit of $f$.

For any other fixed $n$, there must be some $m_n\in\Bbb N$ such that $$g_n(m_n) = 1$$ provided $g_n$ is surjective.  But then the forward-orbit of $f(n)$ is caught in the above 3-cycle, thus the image of $g_n$ is finite, namely
$$|g_n(\Bbb N)|\leqslant m_n+3$$
and hence $g_n$ cannot be surjective.